# Mac OS X - software for storing ideas, code snippets, files, etc

Tags: macos, mac, software-rec

Do you guys know any good free application for Mac OS X, that could store ideas, code snippets, files, etc?

A kind of an organizer for information, files, etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While most of these are not free I highly recommend checking out:

- [Yojimbo](http://www.barebones.com/products/Yojimbo/) - Designed to store passwords, files, notes, etc. I personally use this for one off notes, passwords, etc.
- [EagleFiler](http://c-command.com/eaglefiler/) - Similar in concept to Yojimbo
- [VoodooPad](http://flyingmeat.com/voodoopad/) - A wiki on your desktop, great for storing near everything. That said the free version does not allow embedding files. I personally use this as well and use it for 90% of what you've listed.
- [Code Collector Pro](http://www.mcubedsw.com/software/codecollectorpro) - Fabulous for code snippets, there used to be a Lite (free) version (you can still find it if you search). I've used the Lite version and it was fine for code samples.

Comment: I use Yojimbo, and I love it. But, as mentioned, it's not free.

Answer (score 6):

You could try [Evernote](http://www.evernote.com/). It's cross-platform, can be accessed online:

> Evernote works across the computers and phones you use daily, allowing you to capture something in one place and then access it from another. All inside Evernote.

Comment: This is what I use for everything from links, code, music, ebooks, photos, and almost anything else. Definitely worth getting.

Answer (score 2):

I use [Notational Velocity](http://notational.net/) and sync it up with DropBox. It doesn't hold files, but DropBox will easily sync your files on it's own.

Answer (score 1):

[Evernote](http://www.evernote.com/).

Answer (score 1):

I have tried so many note taking and and digital library apps... but I like the simplicity, and keyboard friendly "Notational Velocity" so much, that I've been using it exclusively for a long, long time.  I actually moved a text dump from my other note apps into Notational Velocity, and now it's pretty much the only way I take notes on my Mac.  It does syncing with a few web providers, and there's even an app that lets you access your Notational Velocity notes on your iPhone/iPod.

At first glance, you might dismiss it for being too lightweight and simple... but it supports tagging, lightning fast search, and it takes up very little space on your screen.  Plus it's very keyboard-oriented/driven, so making new notes is dead-simple, and fast.

Check it out at http://notational.net/

Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

[DevonThink](http://www.devon-technologies.com/products/devonthink/index.html) would do what you want and while it is not free, it was available through Macheist a couple years back, so it appears the developers are open to distributing it inexpensively from time to time.  Keep your eyes open.